# Getting Error in Django Application on Azure App Service

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am getting since yesterday on appliction from yesterday it's working fine early some upgradtion on cloud breaks the application

This is the error

> Error : `module 'typing' has no attribute '_ClassVar'`

My python env is 3.7 and Django version 2.1.3

Comment: Check the version of the Python in your App Service versus the version you use to develop. Check the requirements file and compare that with your development.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below steps if that helps to fix the issue:

- Try downgrading the Python version to 3.6 and check.
- Also, run this command `pip uninstall dataclasses` when using the Python Version 3.7
- As Charlie V Said,

> Check the version of the Python in your App Service versus the version you use to develop. Check the requirements file and compare that with your development.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past. The first thing is determine if your application is actually using this module. If yes, make sure you have it at your requirements.txt. If no, refer to the logs to understand which python file is referencing it and remove the reference for it.